# Sublime Text 2 (or/and Xcode): Alternating background color for consecutive methods/functions?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, coding-style, sublimetext2

I was wondering if there was a way to display methods/functions of a .cpp file with alternating background colors, to easily spot where these methods begin and end when browsing the code. Same question with XCode?

For example:

```
// Here starts light grey bg
void method1(){
...
}

// Now starts dark grey bg
void method2(){
...
}

// Again light grey bg
void method3(){
...
}

// etc...
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about documenting your functions with block comments? Those typically show up in a color that is easily distinguishable from code.

Comment: Hi, this is what I do personally, but where I work we use a certain coding style which does not allow for these kind of separators, sadly, hence my query...